# JavaFX transparency bugged?

Tags: javafx

Here is my code:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      //new Label("TEXT");
      stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
      Pane root = new Pane(new Circle(150,150,50, Color.RED));
      stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.TRANSPARENT));
      stage.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
}
```

If I run it, it displays a red circle on transparent background (as expected).
But if I uncomment the first line (note it just calls the Label constructor and nothing else), suddenly my background is no longer transparent.
Same thing happens if I create a ContextMenu (haven't tried others yet).

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;"); solved this, but note I was not adding anything to the scene, simply instantiating a random component

Comment: See linked question for an explanation of that: "The default user agent stylesheet is loaded the first time a Control is instantiated."